# Leaflet multiple markers but popups don't work

Tags: leaflet

I know I'm missing something, but can't find what.
The following code successfully sets the map and places the pins, but I can't get the popups to pop.
Any ideas on what I'm missing?
Thank you

```
            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: 'Test Map',
                minZoom: 4,
                maxZoom: 4
            })
                .addTo(map);

            $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(idx, obj) {
                 console.log([obj['lat'], obj['lng']]);
                 var marker = L.marker([obj['lat'], obj['lng']])
                     .addTo(map)
                     .bindPopup('test');
            });
```

Comment: Well, but you don't transfer anything to `.bindPopup();`, add some text or whatever you have and then the popup will open. e.g `.bindPopup('help me ;)');`

Comment: I have changed that line to .bindPopup('test');
previously I had other content in there as well... 
there is no popup and no error in console.  I think I'm erasing the popup data over each iteration and I should be adding them to a layer instead (?). I don't know...at a loss.  Thank you

Comment: pls share your full code. the loop is working for me

Comment: `bindPopup` *binds* a popup to a marker but **doesn't** show it. Click on each marker, or run `openPopup` as needed.

Comment: OK ... interesting. 
There is something else that is interrupting the click event... pure vanilla map runs great: 
https://codepen.io/michalsen/pen/oNbPBOo

Thank you all for the time and knowledge above